# How to select a list element and convert it to "float"?

Tags: python

So, I'm currently in the middle of a Python exercise, and I'm struggling with something. I have to make a multiplication between two variables, a and X, but I select `a` inside a list, and `a` is returned as a list with a single element (for example [0.546] instead of 0.546.)

I'd like to convert it into a float element (so 0.546, without the brackets, in my example), but float() doesn't accept a list as an argument. It's probably simple to do, but I'm kind of a Python beginner, and I can't find the answer I want on the Internet (it doesn't help that I'm French.)

Here's my code :

```py
for (i,individual) in iris.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(individual["petal_width"]): 
        a = coeffs["case 1"]['a']     #here I want to select the element 'a' as a float
        b = coeffs["case 1"]['b'] #same thing for b
        X = individual["petal_length"]
        Y = a*X + b
```

By using different print commands, I know that X is a float, so the problem comes from a and b.
Also, when I want to do the multiplication, it says "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float"

Thanks in advance for any help, cheers!

Comment: If it's a list, add `[0]` to select the first element. ;) -> `coeffs["case 1"]['a'][0]`

Comment: Perfect, it works ! I know it would be something simple like that ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You mentioned different print commands, but since you mentioned you're a beginner, did you know about type(x)? print(type(x)) might save time in the future. Also "can't multiply by non-int" may sound weird, but you can in fact try [2] * 3 and get [2, 2, 2] for example. But with a float, you can't get, say, one-half of an element of a list.

Comment: I knew about print(type(x)), that's how I knew it returned a list element. And thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the variable in with `float`, like this:

```
a = float(coeffs["case 1"]['a'])
```

if you want to convert a whole list, not a dict, then you can do this:

```
my_float_list = [float(x) for x in my_list]
```

or

```
my_float_list = list(map(float, my_list))
```

EDIT: Seems like `coeffs["case 1"]['a']` is a list of floats, then do this:

```
# if you are sure that there is atleast one
a = coeffs["case 1"]['a'][0] # if you are sure that there is atleast one value
# if you are unsure that there is atleast one
a = coeffs["case 1"]['a'][0] if len(coeffs["case 1"]['a']) > 0 else 1.0
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot for taking you time to answer ;)